# how to detect rows are subset of other rows and delete them in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, series

I have a large pandas series that each row in it, is a list of numbers.
I want to detect rows that are subset of other rows and delete them from series.

my solution is using 2 for loops but it is very slow. Can anyone help me and introduce a faster way for this because my for loop is very slow.

for example, we must delete rows 2, 4 in the below sample because they are subsets of rows 1, 3 respectively.

```py
import pandas as pd

cycles = pd.Series([[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4], [5, 6, 9, 7], [5, 9]])
```

Comment: if you share you code of what you have done, we can suggest alternatives. I think python comprehensions can be useful for things like this.

Comment: I do not implement my idea because it is very awful. my idea is in O(n**3).

""
for i in df.index:
    for j in df.index:
        check row i is subset of row j and delete i
""

Comment: What is the data type of `cycles`? Is it a list of strings, ints?

Comment: @viggnah this is a list of integers. I know that each list has no duplicate values and you can convert it to set

Comment: @mozway please check my question

Comment: @jezrael please check my question

Answer (score 0):

First, you could sort the lists since they are numbers and convert them to string. Then for every string simply check if it is a substring of any of the other rows, if so it is a subset. Since everything is sorted we can be sure the order of the numbers will not affect this step.

Finally, filter out only the ones that are not identified as a subset.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cycles': [[9, 5, 4, 3], [9, 5, 4], [2, 4, 3], [2, 3]],
    'members': [4, 3, 3, 2]
})
print(df)

         cycles  members
0  [9, 5, 4, 3]        4
1     [9, 5, 4]        3
2     [2, 4, 3]        3
3        [2, 3]        2
```

```py
df['cycles'] = df['cycles'].map(np.sort) 
df['cycles_str'] = [','.join(map(str, c)) for c in df['cycles']]
# Here we check if matches are >1, because it will match with itself once!
df['is_subset'] = [df['cycles_str'].str.contains(c_str).sum() > 1 for c_str in df['cycles_str']]
df = df.loc[df['is_subset'] == False]
df = df.drop(['cycles_str', 'is_subset'], axis=1)

         cycles  members
0  [3, 4, 5, 9]        4
2     [2, 3, 4]        3
```

---

**Edit - The above doesn't work for [1, 2, 4] & [1, 2, 3, 4]**

Rewrote the code. This uses 2 loops and `set` to check for subsets using list comprehension:

```py
# check if >1 True, as it will match with itself once!
df['is_subset'] = [[set(y).issubset(set(x)) for x in df['cycles']].count(True)>1 for y in df['cycles']]
df = df.loc[df['is_subset'] == False]
df = df.drop('is_subset', axis=1)
print(df)

         cycles  members
0  [9, 5, 4, 3]        4
2     [2, 4, 3]        3
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I must test it tommorow and give feedback to you

Comment: I check your code today. your code is logically wrong. suppose that I have two cycle such as [1, 2, 4] and [1, 2, 3,4]. in this case your code can not detect first list as subset of the second. Thank you for your time. if it is possible, please rewrite your code

Comment: @AliM, sorry, didn't check test this simple case. Have updated my answer. It is similar to your initial solution, you can test and see if it is good enough and works for your data.

Comment: thank you very much. but it is not good. my dataframe is too large and this not work.